# jQuery event.stopPropagation is not working on <a>

Tags: events, jquery

I have the following javascript:

```
$('#ge-display').click(function (event) {
  window.open('/googleearth/ge-display.php','','scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,height=650,width=1000,resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,location=no,status=no');
  event.stopPropagation();
  return false;
});
```

the element with id 'ge-display' is a standard link:

```
<a href="/googleearth/ge-display.php" id="ge-display" target="_blank">Load Google Earth Plugin (in a new window)</a>
```

The problem is - when I take out the 'return false;' line from the click event handler, the javascript popup opens, and then another browser window opens - I thought stopPropagation() would prevent the links own click handler?

I've also tried stopImmediatePropagation() - but I still need to return false to stop the default behaviour of the link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Calling [`event.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) will prevent other Javascript event handlers from handling that event.  It will not prevent the browser's default action.

You need to call [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).